# How to calculate month-to-date and year-to-date averages by category in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe of several categories of time series of one year which looks like this:

```
   category        date  price
0          A 2022-12-19      5
1          A 2022-12-16      5
2          A 2022-12-15     21
3          A 2022-12-14     21
4          A 2022-12-13     15
5          A 2022-12-12     18
6          B 2022-12-19     48
7          B 2022-12-16     92
8          B 2022-12-15    212
9          B 2022-12-14    185
10         B 2022-12-13    874
11         B 2022-12-12     51
12         C 2022-12-19     15
13         C 2022-12-16     65
14         C 2022-12-15    874
15         C 2022-12-14    485
16         C 2022-12-13     52
17         C 2022-12-12     99
```

I wish to calculate the month-to-date and year-to-date average price for each category, AND keep automatically the last 2 working day data for each category

For example today is the 19th Dec, the YtD average would be the average prices from start Jan 2022 till today, while the MtD average would be the average prices starting 2022-12-01 till today.

Pandas doesn't seem to have a method to calculate the YtD and MtD average.

Answer (score 0):

With the following version of your dataframe, modified to provied more meaningful dates for the purpose of demonstration:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "category": [
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "C",
            "C",
            "C",
            "C",
            "C",
            "C",
        ],
        "date": [
            "2022-12-19",
            "2022-12-16",
            "2022-10-15",
            "2022-04-14",
            "2022-02-13",
            "2022-01-12",
            "2022-12-19",
            "2022-12-16",
            "2022-10-15",
            "2022-04-14",
            "2022-02-13",
            "2022-01-12",
            "2022-12-19",
            "2022-12-16",
            "2022-10-15",
            "2022-04-14",
            "2022-02-13",
            "2022-01-12",
        ],
        "price": [
            5,
            5,
            21,
            21,
            15,
            18,
            48,
            92,
            212,
            185,
            874,
            51,
            15,
            65,
            874,
            485,
            52,
            99,
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [date offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/offset_frequency.html), and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
current_wk_day = pd.to_datetime("2022-12-19")
month_begin = current_wk_day - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
year_begin = current_wk_day - pd.offsets.YearBegin()
previous_wk_day = current_wk_day - pd.offsets.BusinessDay()

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df[df["date"] >= month_begin].groupby("category").mean(numeric_only=True),
        df[df["date"] >= year_begin].groupby("category").mean(numeric_only=True),
        df[df["date"] >= previous_wk_day].groupby("category").agg(list),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
df.columns = [
    "month-to-date_avg",
    "year-to-date_avg",
    "last_two_wk_days",
    "last_two_wk_days_prices",
]
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
          month-to-date_avg  year-to-date_avg  \
category
A                       5.0         14.166667   
B                      70.0        243.666667   
C                      40.0        265.000000   

                                    last_two_wk_days last_two_wk_days_prices  
category
A         [2022-12-19 00:00:00, 2022-12-16 00:00:00]                  [5, 5]  
B         [2022-12-19 00:00:00, 2022-12-16 00:00:00]                [48, 92]  
C         [2022-12-19 00:00:00, 2022-12-16 00:00:00]                [15, 65]
```